# Chrome Extension: How can I access the new document on page changes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to amend the DOM using a chrome extension. Unfortunately I fail with accessing the new page after some of the actions cause a page change. My code looks like this:

**content_script.js**

```
(async () => {
  try { 
    execute_edit = async () => {
      console.log(document.title)
      const el = document.getElementsByClassName("icon")
      const first_el = el[0]
      first_el.click()
    }

    change_element = async () => {
      console.log(document.title)
      const el = document.querySelector("element")
      console.log(el.innerHTML)
    }

    await execute_edit()
    await change_element()
  } catch (e) { 
    console.log(e)
  }
})();
```

I'm getting the error that the "el" in "change_element" does not exist. This is obviously caused by the fact that both "document.title" are identical i.e. the second function still tries to access the original DOM and not the new page.

Any suggestions on how I can have the second function "change_element" access the new page's DOM?

Comment: Either 1) a new page loads in which case the old content script terminates and then runs from the start again in a new clean environment of the new page or 2) DOM of the same page is updated which you can detect via MutationObserver.

Comment: This is case 1. Will the content script always run from the start or do I have to add a listener for page update to the background.js? I assume it would be best practice to check for the URL and then execute functions depending on that since I want to run different functions on different pages. Is there a variable I have access to in the content script that gives me the URL or should I get that value via the listener?

Comment: It'll be like closing the old page completely and opening a new page in a new tab. Everything is new including the URL which you can see via `location.href`, no need for the background script. You can use chrome.storage.session to persist the state.

Comment: So I tried this but the content script does only run once. It does not execute again when the new page loads.

Comment: It means the second option (MutationObserver).